# How to get the items of a Database by ID?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a quiz-like application and I can't seem to get the questions by "Category" (the category is an ID, because it will be assigned to different locations)

I have this method:

```
public List<Question> getAllKerdesByHelyID(int ID){
        {
            List<Question> questionlist = new ArrayList<Question>();

            String selectQuery= " SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST + "WHERE " + KEY_HELYID + " = " + ID;

            dbase = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Question quest = new Question();
                    quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                    quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
                    quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
                    quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
                    quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
                    quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(5));
                    quest.setID(cursor.getInt(6));
                    questionlist.add(quest);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            // return quest list
            return questionlist;

        }
    }
```

For now i'm just creating the application so not all feautre is implemented.
KEY_HELYID should be the integer i'm trying to filter.

quesList=db.getAllKerdesByHelyID(5); is how i'm calling this method on the activity.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: can you print the full select query in log and paste it?

Comment: you mean like Log.d("Query: " + quest.getQuestion + quest.getAnswer ..) ?

Comment: I believe that by logging you found the typo I hope I have helped also if you find the typo it would be good to put the solution and mark it as a answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem, the table was empty because of a typo in the creation of the database table